# Query in create table to ensure email format that ends with either ‘@gmail.com’ or ‘@ymail.com’ or @yahoo.co.id’

Tags: sql-server

I have tried using | but still error

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator.

Any advice?

```
StaffEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK(StaffEmail LIKE '%@gmail.com' | '%@ymail.com' | '%@yahoo.co.id')
```

Comment: Still error An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.

Comment: Sorry, you have to repeat the test `(StaffEmail LIKE '%@gmail.com' OR StaffEmail LIKE '%@ymail.com' OR StaffEmail LIKE '%@yahoo.co.id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table test001 (
    StaffEmail VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL CHECK(
       StaffEmail LIKE '%@gmail.com' or
       StaffEmail LIKE '%@ymail.com' or
       StaffEmail LIKE '%@yahoo.co.id')
);
```

When you use `LIKE` and want to compare multiple such wildcards, include your fieldname like this:  like '%your-wildcard%' or  like '%another%' or  like '%yet-another%'